# Вывод авторов по их публикациям в WordPress + ACF?

Tags: wordpress

**Дано:**
Есть авторы, сделанные через Custom Post Type
Есть статьи, где в Custom Field указывается автор через объект записи из списка
Есть archive-authors Вывод всех авторов списком

**Вопрос.** Как сделать фильтрацию авторов, исходя из новизны статьей в котором они указаны.

**Пример**
Есть Автор №1. Автор №2, Автор №3, Автор №4
Автор №4 написал статью вчера,
Автор №2 Написал статью позавчера
Автор №1 написал статью год назад
Автор №3 Написал статью сегодня

Т.е их вывод на странице должен быть Автор №3, Автор №4, Автор №2, Автор №1

Прошу помочь с логикой, к каким данным стоит апеллировать дабы получить их последовательность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так: при сохранении публикации я бы записывал последнее изменение записи в пост мету для автора. Текущих авторов прогнал бы разок в БД, чтобы заполнить это.

Если вы не хотите хранить последнюю записиь в пост мете, то запрос сложным и тяжелым...

Comment: Согласен, плюсанул.

Comment: А каким образом лучше всего сделать эту пометку

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa храните дату в удобном формате. Можете хранить в timestamp а потом выводить, как вам удобно.